# Smooth Scrolling with Sticky Menu

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

now this is my problem, this is a one page website with stickymenu (#main-menu). The #main-menu is fixed on that position. The first image shows what should the page looks when i click on the "About" link on menu, the page will scroll smoothly on #about.

[image: Image One]

But here on Image Two, is what does my site is rendering, when i click on "About" Link, the About Us title scrolls till the top and hid on the #main-menu.

[image: Image Two]

Here is my JS code:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 800, 'easeInOutCirc');
    });
```

How do i make it stop up until the #main-menu bottom only? Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 3):

you want to subtract your header's height from the offsetTop.

```
$('html').animate({ // $(document.documentElement) works too
  scrollTop: Math.max($(target).offset().top - $('#your-header').outerHeight(), 0)
}, 800, 'easeInOutCirc');
```

add the Math.max( ... , 0) to avoid scrolling to a negative offset when your link destination is at the very top.

Comment: Is it actually possible to scroll to a negative position?

Comment: trying it in firefox scrolls to 0. But you never know what browser x does under circumstance y.

Comment: This works perfectly! But can i like add like a margin +10px after the outerHeight of the #main-menu on this code? So the title wont stick to much on the bottom edge. Thanks again a lot!

Comment: sure, `scrollTop: Math.max($(target).offset().top - $('#your-header').outerHeight() + 20, 0)` does the trick ;)